# What basis we should select the number of partition in re-partition in Dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What basis we should decide on the number of partitions while re-partitioning a Data-frame based on the memory core? Value should be based on the number of available core or multiples of number of core available ?

Comment: rule of thumb is taking a look at your input file and divide it by 250 to 300.. that should give you the # of partitions on your DF